# Capitalizing Adjectives: Is it for Emphasis?

Tags: punctuation

Mary Karr wrote in her memoirs, "Mother had been taken Away--he further told us--for being Nervous". Why are the words "away" and "nervous" capitalized?

Comment: It's old fashioned.

Comment: After having attempted my own answer, I think this question might get a better answer on [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/). The capitals are indeed for emphasis, but Literature could go further in-depth on what they're intended to do in the text.

Answer (score 3):

Having read through part of the original source, I think these are not errors, but have been used by the author to mark euphemisms. The nuance is that "Mother had been taken to a place named "Away" (actually a mental asylum) for having a condition named "Nervous" (actually a serious mental breakdown)"

The narrator (who is reporting this speech) doesn't understand the true meaning of the words. The meaninglessness of the words is highlighted by treating them as proper nouns. She later capitalizes "Not Right", and similarly "Mother" and "Daddy" are capitalised. From the point of view of the child narrator, these are names.

This is a subtle bit of emphasis done by a skilled writer, and add nuance to a scene.

Comment: @ James K - "I think these are not errors, but have been used by the author to mark euphemisms." Absolutely.